# Review status revoked

Tags: support, review-suspension

Just checked my SO today and find that I'm suspended from reviewing suggested edits for a couple of weeks.

Three reviews were flagged:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15318385 https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15318442
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15317515

The first one, fair enough, I agree, my review was incorrect, I was unaware that using official documentation was discouraged. However, the second one in the list was actually approved (the review was changing a post from entirely in bold to entirely in standard weight. Surely an entire post should not be bold, hence why the review was eventually approved?) so I don't understand why this was flagged?

I'm not disputing why my review status has been temporarily revoked, there were clearly issues with the first approval, but the second and third are not so clear and I want to improve to avoid this issue in future.

Comment: The second review was approved, because you clicked "Improve Edit", instead of rejecting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second one should not have been edited in the first place. It is a textbook off-topic question and should be closed as Primarily Opinion Based.

Approving these edits sends the wrong message; it sends the message that "polishing a turd" is OK.

The third one adds code for a new version. There is a little controversy about this, but most users on MSO oppose this. Adding code for a new version is better done as a separate answer. Especially if the existing answer is highly upvoted, because if the new code is accidentally wrong, we don't want it to look like the wrong code got all these upvotes.
Also, it breaks the code formatting, making it harder to read.

Regarding the first one, there may be a misunderstanding here: we do not discourage using official documentation, we discourage *plagiarism*. Whether the plagiarism is from the official documentation or another source does not matter.

Most of the time, when people copy-paste official documentation into a tag wiki, it's just rep-farming. However, *properly selected* and properly attributed, quotes from the official documentation are a great addition to an answer or tag wiki. The key phrase is "properly selected" - the editor should add the things that are important or relevant.

Comment: @Dan True enough. All we can do is vote to close them. Nitpick: "polishing a turd" usually refers to editing bad posts here, not to answering them.